# How to change language of the build in VS2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, translation, locale

I have some MFC application that use russian language, but now I want to translate interface and make build for english version of windows.

What is the usual way to change language in VS2008 build?

I found this code in *.rc file

```
// Russian resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_RUS)
#ifdef _WIN32
LANGUAGE LANG_RUSSIAN, SUBLANG_DEFAULT
#pragma code_page(1251)
#endif //_WIN32
```

and also

```
#define TEXT_LOCALE_ID          (MAKELCID( MAKELANGID(LANG_RUSSIAN, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), SORT_DEFAULT ))
```

in some *.h file where I store strings in format such as

```
#define SOME_STR_RUS  _T("Строка на русском")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try converting every "russian" term into an english term.
Such as :

1)defined(AFX_TARG_ENG)
2)LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_DEFAULT
3) (MAKELCID(MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLAND_ENGLISH),SORT_DEFAULT))

This worked for me.
By changing the russian terms to universal english terms, you'd be setting the default language and acting language to your choice.